# Что такое <devdoc>?

Tags: c#, .net

Копался в исходниках **.NET Framework** и обнаружил непонятные мне комментарии. Что это за теги `<devdoc>` что они дают и как ими пользоваться?

> ```
> /// <include file='doc\Application.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Application"]/*' />
> /// <devdoc>
> /// <para>Provides <see langword='static '/>
> /// methods and properties
> /// to manage an application, such as methods to run and quit an application,
> /// to process Windows messages, and properties to get information about an application. This
> /// class cannot be inherited.</para>
> /// </devdoc>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как можно догадаться `devdoc` означает developer documentation, т.е. комменты для девелоперов.

[Тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/internal-coding-guidelines) в пункте 2.4.2 чуть более подробно.

Comment: А все остальные комментарии для кого?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin `include` это не совсем комментарий, это ссылка  на внешний файл с xml документацией. Рекомендую таки ознакомится с информацией по ссылке.

Comment: Причем тут include, я же про <devdoc> спросил. Ссылку которую Вы привели я читал еще до того как задать вопрос. Там непонятно. Сказано, "для внутренних dev комментариев должен использоваться тег <devdoc>". dev - надо полагать означает "девелоперов, разработчиков". Это в точности повторяет Ваши слова. Поэтому я и спрашиваю - если это комментарии для разработчиков, то остальные комментарии для кого? Чем принципиально отличаются комментарии заключенные в тег <devdoc> от остальных комментариев?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin, тем, что они в xml.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin это просто соглашение. Содержание `devdoc` не будет выводится при наведении на метод например. Как правило содержимое этого аттрибута будет игнорироваться генераторами документации. Это содержимое написаное девами для девов.